# PHP MySQL: boolean Value works on local server but returns empty on live server?

Tags: php, mysql, database, web, server

I have a boolean ( bit ) value stored in my database. The problem is when I run the PHP script on local server I get the value either 0 or 1 depending upon the value stored in Database against the id using mySQL query. However the same script on live server returns absolutely nothing neither 0 nor 1. My variable remains empty. Any possible explanation. The value of $status remains empty on live server but works on local

```
    <?php
session_start();

require_once __DIR__ . '/connect.php';

if (!$_SESSION['loginadmin'])
{
    header("location:error.php");
}
else
{

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!---->
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>

<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="bootstrapTheme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Owl Carousel Assets -->
<link href="owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all">
<script src="js/Forum_400.font.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>

<!--Login Button scripts-->
<script type="application/x-javascript"> addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); } </script>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/megamenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/menu_jquery.js"></script>

<!--**********-->

</head>
<body id="page1">
<div class="body6">
  <div class="body1">
    <div class="body5">
      <div class="main">
        <!-- header -->
        <header>
          <h1><a href="index.php" ><div id="logo"><img src="images/logo.png" / ></div></a></h1>
          <nav>
            <ul id="top_nav">
              <li><a href="index.php"><img src="images/icon_1.gif" alt="">HOME</a></li>              
               <li class="login" >
                        <div id="loginContainer"><a href="signout.php"><img src="images/icon_2.png" alt=""><span>SIGN OUT</span></a>

                  </div>
            </li>
            <li class="end"><a href="contact.html"><img src="images/icon_3.gif" alt="">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>

        </header>
<!---->
<div class="contact-bg">
     <div class="container">
          <div class="contact-us">              

                <div class="contact_right">
                  <div class="contact-form">
                    <h3 class="style">ADMINISTRATOR PANEL</h3>
                        <form method="post" action="status.php">
                            <div>
                                <span><label>Membership ID</label></span>
                                <span><input name="membership" type="text" class="textbox"></span>
                            </div>

                          <div>
                                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Check">
                          </div>

<?php




if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $_SESSION['id']=$_POST['membership'];
    $membership=$_POST['membership'];
    $first_id=0;


            if(($membership=="" && $membership==NULL))
            {
                echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('We are sorry ! But you have missed the field');</script>";
            }
            else
            {

            $query0 = "LOCK TABLES card WRITE";
            $result0 = mysql_query($query0);

            $query1 = "LOCK TABLES card as card1 READ";
            $result1 = mysql_query($query0);





            if( $result0 && $result1 )
            {

                $query = "SELECT status FROM card WHERE id='$membership'";

                $result = mysql_query($query);
                $numberofrows = mysql_num_rows ($result);

                $query_ = "UNLOCK TABLES";
                mysql_query($query_);       




                if($numberofrows)
                {
                    $row=mysql_fetch_row($result,MYSQL_ASSOC);
                    $status = $row['status'];

                    $sql = "SELECT name FROM customers WHERE mem_id='$membership'";
                    $res = mysql_query($sql);
                    $numberofrows = mysql_num_rows($res);


                if (!$status)
                {   
                    ?>
                    <div>

                                <?php 
                                if ($numberofrows)
                                {   
                                    $row=mysql_fetch_row($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
                                    $memname = $row['name'];
                                    echo "<span><label>Name: $memname $status</label></span>";
                                }
                                else
                                    echo "<span><label>No User Against this Membership ID</label></span>";
                                ?>

                                <span><label>Current Status: Not Activated</label></span>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                <input type="submit" name="activate" value="Activate">
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }

                else
                {   
                    ?>
                    <div>
                                <?php if ($numberofrows)
                                {   
                                    $row=mysql_fetch_row($res,MYSQL_ASSOC);
                                    $memname = $row['name'];

                                    echo "<span><label>Name: $memname $status</label></span>";
                                }
                                else
                                    echo "<span><label>No User Against this Membership ID</label></span>";
                                ?>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                <span><label>Current Status: Activated </label></span>
                                <input type="submit" name="deactivate" value="Deactivate">
                    </div>
                    <?php


                }
                }
                else
                  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('No such membership id');</script>";



            $query_ = "UNLOCK TABLES";
            mysql_query($query_);       


            }
                else
                 die ("Database access failed: " . mysql_error());

            }


    //  }

}

if(isset($_POST['activate']))
{

    $query="UPDATE card SET status=TRUE WHERE id='$_SESSION[id]'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result)
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('membership id: $_SESSION[id] Status Changed to ACTIVATED');</script>";

}   
if(isset($_POST['deactivate']))
{
    $query="UPDATE card SET status=FALSE WHERE id='$_SESSION[id]'";
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result)
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('membership id: $_SESSION[id] Status Changed to Deactivated');</script>";

}   
}

?>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>      
                <div class="clear"></div>       
          </div>
     </div> 
</div>   
<!---->

<footer>
 <div id="wrapper">
 <section class="col1 pad_left1">

<div id="end">
<div id="end_menu">
             <a href="index.php"> Home </a> . <a href="#">About</a> . <a href="#">Contact</a> . <a href="#">Terms of Use</a> . <a href="#">Sponsors</a> 

</div>
<div id="social">          
            <ul id="icons">
              <li><a href="#" class="normaltip"><img src="images/icon1.gif" alt=""></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="normaltip"><img src="images/icon2.gif" alt=""></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="normaltip"><img src="images/icon3.gif" alt=""></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="normaltip"><img src="images/icon4.gif" alt=""></a></li>
              <li><a href="#" class="normaltip"><img src="images/icon5.gif" alt=""></a></li>
            </ul>
</div>
<div id="sponsors">
<img src="images/g1.png" width="150px" height="100px"/>
<img src="images/g2.png" width="150px" height="100px"/>
</div>
<div id="subscribe">
<span class="toto">NEWSLETTER</span><br>
<input type="text" id="inputs" placeholder="e-mail" /> 
<br>
<div id="sub_but">
SUBSCRIBE
</div>
</div>
</div>
</section>
</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look atthe php error log (file) on that server. Could be for example a start-up error -> your script hasn't been executed at all

Comment: The script executes and it straight away goes into the ELSE part since the corresponding IF part is dependent on the boolean value.

Comment: And the query also runs successfully because the script only runs the rest code if the query is executed successfully. Then again I am not able to get why it is working fine on local server and not on live server

Comment: That's kinda inconsistent with your above statement `however the same script on live server returns absolutely nothing neither 0 nor 1.`

Comment: That is the inconsistency I am trying to figure out !! I get values on local server but I dont get any value when I am on live server.

Comment: The problem is in the `if(isset($_POST['activate']))... ` and  `if(isset($_POST['deactivate'])) ....` parts of the script? You don't have an error handling in there - unlike in some way in the other parts of the script.

Comment: There is no error handling there but the thing is it works fine on the local server and it isnt giving any error on live server .. All I am concerned is that I am not able to get value in my $status variable which handles my IF ELSE !!

Comment: `I am not able to get value in my $status variable` - so it's about the `if($numberofrows) { ... if (!$status) ... {` part of the script?

Comment: Yes its about that part !

Comment: Then concentrate your efforts on puttin in more error handling and debug output there. An unconditional `var_export($numberofrows)` before `if($numberofrows)`, a `print_r($sql, $res, $numberofrows, $status);` before `if (!$status)` there - just to pinpoint the problem....

Comment: `The value of $status remains empty on live server but works on local` you have many lines with `$status` which one bother you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the status value as BIT on my local server which was working fine on the local server however it was returning empty on live server.
FIX ON LIVE SERVER: Changed the status column type from BIT to TINYINT on live server.